# Stepped line with null values in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have data: `[10,5,null,10,5]`, and labels: `[2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]`

I'd like to draw a stepped line which has a gap between `2012` and `2013`.
When I set `steppedLine` to `true`, it only drew a vertical line at `2011` but no horizontal line to connect `2011` and `2012`, as the value of `2012` is `null`. If I set `spanGaps` to `true`, it will draw a line from `2011` to `2013` at value `5`.

Basically what I'm looking for is to draw a line if the starting value is a number and the ending value is `null`, but not vice versa

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/vz4qhqpw/)

Related codes in controller:

```
    _this.lines = {};
    _this.lines.labels = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014];
    _this.lines.data = [
        [10, 5, null, 10, 5]    
    ];
    _this.lines.series = ['Now'];
    _this.lines.options = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    parser: 'DD MMM YYYY'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    };
    _this.lines.datasetOverride = [{
        fill: false,
        spanGaps: true,
        steppedLine: true
        },
    ];
```

HTML:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-labels="ctrl.lines.labels" chart-data="ctrl.lines.data" chart-options="ctrl.lines.options" chart-series="ctrl.lines.series" chart-dataset-override="ctrl.lines.datasetOverride" height="140" responsive=true></canvas>
```

Comment: can you add a code snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what you want but you can just add another point at `2012` with the same value as `2011` and then another data point at `2012` will `null` so it'll create a gap between `2012` and `2013`, although it will create a point at `2012`.

[image]

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pb5z2c9d/)

```
_this.lines.labels = [2010,2011,2012,2012,2013,2014];
_this.lines.data = [
    [10, 5,5,null, 10, 5]    
];
```

This would be the only change to your current code